# Find the present value of installment payments of \$1000 now, \$2000 at the end of the first year

Tags: economics

I was helping a comrade how to answer this engineering economics question. It goes like this:

> Find the present value of installment payments of \$1000 now, \$2000 at the end of the first year, \$3000 at the end of second year, \$4000 at the end of the third year, \$5000 at the end of the fourth year, if money is worth 10% compounded annually.

**My work**

I thought the present worth is the future worth of money 4 years from now.

Using the basic formula $F = P(1+i)^n$, where $F$ is future worth, $P$ is the principal, $i$ is the interest rate, and $n$ is the number of years, we can answer the question using this approach:

When I pay now:
$$\$1000$$

When 1 year has elapsed, I pay $\$2000$ and my $\$1000$ was earning already.
$$\$2000 + \$1000(1+0.1)^1 = \$3100$$

When 2 years has elapsed, I pay $\$3000$ and my $\$2000$ and $\$1000$ was earning already.
$$\$3000 + \$2000(1+0.1)^1 + \$1000(1+0.1)^2 = \$6410$$

When 3 years has elapsed, I pay $\$4000$ and my $\$3000$, $\$2000$ and $\$1000$ was earning already.
$$\$4000 + \$3000(1+0.1)^1 + \$2000(1+0.1)^2 + \$1000(1+0.1)^3 = \$11051$$

When 4 years has elapsed, I pay $\$5000$ and my $\$4000$, $\$3000$, $\$2000$ and $\$1000$ was earning already.
$$\$5000 + \$4000(1+0.1)^1 + \$3000(1+0.1)^2 + \$2000(1+0.1)^3 + \$1000(1+0.1)^4 = \$17156.10$$

The present value of installment payments, therefore, would be:
$$\$1000 + \$3100 +\$6410 +\$11051 +\$17156.10 = \$38717.10$$

Is my answer correct? Is it any good?

**Edit**

Someone said that I just found the future value, not the present one. With that in mind, to get the present value, do this:

When I pay now:
$$\$1000$$

When 1 year has elapsed, I pay $\$2000$ and my $\$1000$ present value has changed already.
$$\$2000 + \frac{\$1000}{(1+0.1)^1} = \$2909.09$$

When 2 years has elapsed, I pay $\$3000$ and my $\$2000$ and $\$1000$ present value has changed already.
$$\$3000 + \frac{\$2000}{(1+0.1)^1} + \frac{\$1000}{(1+0.1)^2} = \$5644.63$$

When 3 years has elapsed, I pay $\$4000$ and my $\$3000$, $\$2000$ and $\$1000$ present value has changed already.
$$\$4000 + \frac{\$3000}{(1+0.1)^1} + \frac{\$2000}{(1+0.1)^2} + \frac{\$1000}{(1+0.1)^3} = \$9131.48$$

When 4 years has elapsed, I pay $\$5000$ and my $\$4000$, $\$3000$, $\$2000$ and $\$1000$ present value has changed already.
$$\$5000 + \frac{\$4000}{(1+0.1)^1} + \frac{\$3000}{(1+0.1)^2} + \frac{\$2000}{(1+0.1)^3} + \frac{\$1000}{(1+0.1)^4} = \$13301.34$$

The present value of installment payments, therefore, would be:
$$\$1000 + \$2909.09 +\$5644.63 + \$9131.48 + $\$1301.34$= \$31986.54$$

Is my answer now correct? Is it any good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you want the **present value**.  What you have computed is the **future value**.

The present value can be thought of as the equivalent amount of money that would be paid up front as a lump sum, which has the same time value of money as the cash flow in question.

For example, if I say that $2000$ will be paid to you one year from now, and the effective annual rate of interest is $i = 0.1$, the present value of this payment is the amount which, if held by you over the same amount of time, would equal $2000$ at the end of one year.  That is to say, $$PV(1+i) = 2000,$$ or $$PV = \frac{2000}{1.1} \approx 1818.18.$$  It should be clear that for a positive interest rate, the longer the deferral of the payment, the less its present value, since you have to wait longer to receive it.  So for example, if I said that the same $2000$ will be paid to you in $10$ years from now, the present value is $2000/(1.1)^{10} \approx 771.09$.  That decrease in value is a reflection of the fact that you could take $771.09$ now and assuming a constant effective annual interest rate of $10\%$ per year, it would grow to $2000$ at the end of $10$ years if the interest is compounded annually.

With this understanding, try recomputing the present value of your cash flow.

Comment: I got the answer of $\$31986.54$ as a present value. Is this correct?

Comment: So...you mean that receiving $\$1818.18$ now and receiving $\$2000$ after a year, assuming its annual interest rate is 0.1, means the same thing?

Comment: @PalautotKa In regard to your second comment, yes, that is precisely what I mean.  Your present value $31986.54$ cannot be correct because it is much larger than the total sum paid, which is $15000$, yet most of the payments are deferred into the future.

Comment: I added something on the question posted, after I understood your hint....That's how I get $\$31986.54$ as a present value....

Comment: What does the number $13301.34$ represent?  Is it being calculated using all five payments?  If so, why are you then going back and adding in all the other numbers you computed again to get $31986.54$?  If I pay you $1000$ now and $2000$ a year from now, then the **total** present value is $1000$ plus $2000/1.1$.  Why would you then go back and add another $1000$ from nowhere?  You already took that payment into account.

Comment: Furthermore, your calculation of $13301.34$ doesn't correspond to the order in which the payments are made.  $5000$ is paid at the end of four years, so the present value of this one payment is $5000/(1.1)^4$.

Comment: I see now.....It must have been $\$1000 + \frac{\$2000}{(1+0.1)^1} + \frac{\$3000}{(1+0.1)^2} + \frac{\$4000}{(1+0.1)^3} + \frac{\$5000}{(1+0.1)^4} = \$11717.84$....Am I right?

Comment: That is correct.